# How would I get the information from my dropdown menu to add to my array using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I have a number of fields that need to be complete. However, for one of them, I have used the drop down menu and I am unsure on how to retrieve the data. For the entry fields, I just use .get() and then paste them into the array.

```
    OPTIONS = [
        "What was my first pet's name?",
        "What was your favorite food as a child?",
        "What was the make of your first car?",
        "What is your mother's maiden name?"
    ]

    variable = StringVar(fp_frame)
    variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # Default value

    w = OptionMenu(fp_frame, variable, *OPTIONS)
    w.place(x=660, y=425, width = 240, height = 28)
```

This is the code for my drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at *[How can I get the index of a selected option in a Tkinter Combobox?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-index-of-selected-option-in-tkinter-combobox/)*.

So use the following code:

```py
str(combo.current())
```